# Json get fitting the numbers in a row and add a 0 in front of every 1-9 number

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed, jq

In bash i want to make the .txt file to have the link in line 1. and the numbers in line 2.

```
curl -s "http://kodi:kodi@192.168.1.10:8080/jsonrpc?Base" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '[{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Player.GetProperties","params":[1,["time"]],"id":17},{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Player.GetItem","params":[1,["file"]],"id":18}]' | jq
```

json file format with jq

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "id": 17,
>     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
>     "result": {
>       "time": {
>         "hours": 2,
>         "milliseconds": 200,
>         "minutes": 3,
>         "seconds": 5
>       }
>     }
>   },
>   {
>     "id": 18,
>     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
>     "result": {
>       "item": {
>         "file": "plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id=rhMTZB2WJWA",
>         "label": "FULL SHOW - Burton US Open Men's Slopestyle Semi-Finals",
>         "type": "unknown"
>       }
>     }
>   }
> ]
> ```

```
curl -s "http://kodi:kodi@192.168.1.10:8080/jsonrpc?Base" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '[{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Player.GetProperties","params":[1,["time"]],"id":17},{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Player.GetItem","params":[1,["file"]],"id":18}]' | jq --raw-output '.[].result.item.file, .[].result.time.hours, .[].result.time.minutes, .[].result.time.seconds | select(. != null)' > "c:\kodi\info.txt"
```

with this i can get this format in the info.txt file

info.txt

> ```
> plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id=rhMTZB2WJWA
> 2
> 3
> 5
> ```

example 2.

> ```
> plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id=rhMTZB2WJWA
> 0
> 11
> 22
> ```

example 3.

> ```
> plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id=rhMTZB2WJWA
> 0
> 55
> 9
> ```

[online jq play link](https://jqplay.org/s/xTHa1D-5jI)

**how could it be done with jq, awk, paste, sed or something similar to make it look like this and put a 0 in front of every 1-9?**

```
example 1.
plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id=rhMTZB2WJWA
020305
    
example 2.
plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id=rhMTZB2WJWA
001122

example 3. 
plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id=rhMTZB2WJWA
005509
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I suspect this might not be possible with jq alone until https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1341 is complete.

Comment: @jordanm 
thx for the reply actually I can use combination with other things e.g. 
| awk 'command' | jq 'command' | sed 'command' > .txt
with any of these combinations there must be someone who can help me

Comment: There are several blocks of text in your question, please [edit] it to clearly state which is your sample input and which is your expected output. I think that last block is probably expected output but then where did the text `example 1.` come from and is that supposed to be 3 separate outputs from 3 separate files or something else? Just please clean it up and make it clear.

Comment: @EdMorton ok sorry just trying not to miss anything
I'll fix it

Comment: Can use `printf` for this sort of formatting... ie ` printf '%02d%02d%02d' $(printf '1\n2\n3\n' | xargs) ` gives you `010203` ... so, take the stream in which you create info.txt, pipe it to xargs, and then use those args to call printf to format those args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==1 {print;next}          # print line 1 as is
       {printf "%02d",$1}    # print all other lines on 2nd line (notice no "\n"),
                             # left padding numbers with "0" to 2 digits
END    {printf "\n"}         # print EOL
' file
```

Assuming the 3 samples of data are in files `file{1..3}`:

```
for f in file{1..3}
do
    echo "+++++++++++ ${f}"
    awk 'FNR==1 {print;next} {printf "%02d",$1} END {printf "\n"}' "${f}"
done
```

This generates:

```
+++++++++++ file1
plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id=rhMTZB2WJWA
020305
+++++++++++ file2
plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id=rhMTZB2WJWA
001122
+++++++++++ file3
plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id=rhMTZB2WJWA
005509
```

Comment: `printf "\n"` = `print ""`. nbd but `print ""` is slightly briefer and will work for any value of ORS rather than assuming ORS is `"\n"`.

Comment: @markp-fuso thanks for the answer and the explanation, it works perfectly!:)

Answer (score 3):

Do it with `jq` entirely:

```sh
jq --raw-output '[.[].result] | add | .item.file, ( .time | .hours * 3600 + .minutes * 60 + .seconds | strftime("%H%M%S") )'
```

The `jq` script with comments:

`jqscript`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S jq -fr

# Merge all result entries into a single object
[.[].result] | add |

# Output the file url
  .item.file,

# Output a formatted time
  (
    # Using the time object
    .time |
      # Compute a timestamp in seconds
      .hours * 3600 + .minutes * 60 + .seconds |
        # Format the timestamp to requirement
        strftime("%H%M%S")
  )
```

`input.json`

```json
[
  {
    "id": 17,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
      "time": {
        "hours": 2,
        "milliseconds": 200,
        "minutes": 3,
        "seconds": 5
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
      "item": {
        "file": "plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id=rhMTZB2WJWA",
        "label": "FULL SHOW - Burton US Open Men's Slopestyle Semi-Finals",
        "type": "unknown"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Running:

```sh
./jqscript input.json
```

Output:

```
plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id=rhMTZB2WJWA
020305
```

Comment: When I run that one-line script with `jq-1.6` I get `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0`. I don't know `jq` well enough to debug it.

Comment: @LéaGris thank you (i tested it with a .sh file) this is also a good solution!

Comment: @EdMorton if you try with online jq paste this in FILTER 
`.[0].result + .[1].result | .item.file, ( .time | .hours * 3600 + .minutes * 60 + .seconds | strftime("%H%M%S") )` also check raw output  if you look at the bottom of the command line part it will look like what Léa wrote

Comment: @ÁdámHegedüs I have no doubt it works as shown with some versions of `jq`.

Comment: @EdMorton Using `dpkg-query --show jq` → `jq 1.6-1ubuntu0.20.10.1`

Comment: I'm on cygwin. I just reintsalled jq so according to https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/jq.html I should also be on jq 1.6-1 but I still get the same parse error. Maybe it's a cygwin thing, idk, I haven't used jq much.