# What is the equivalent of this Curl command in python3?

Tags: json, python-3.x, bash, curl, python-requests

Should only be done with python3.

As i am not familiar with python3 i would like a full answer
and not just a snippet. Thank you if you take this into consideration!

```
curl -s "http://kodi:kodi@192.168.1.10:8080/jsonrpc?Base" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '[{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Player.GetProperties","params":[1,["time"]],"id":17},{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Player.GetItem","params":[1,["file"]],"id":18}]'
```

this is what I get for the curl command:

```
[{"id":17,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"time":{"hours":0,"milliseconds":597,"minutes":44,"seconds":53}}},{"id":18,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"item":{"file":"smb://192.168.1.10/@.mkv","id":340,"label":"The Expendables 3","type":"movie"}}}]
```

from which I would get the values of "file", "hours", "minutes", and "seconds"
in front of hours, minutes, and seconds, if the number is 0-9 then put a 0 in front of it and save it in a .txt file

the .txt file should look like this:

```
smb://192.168.1.10/@.mkv
004453
```

exaple 2.

```
smb://192.168.1.10/@.mkv
010703
```

example 3.

```
smb://192.168.1.10/@.mkv
025547
```

**bash solution, and more information here:**
[I got very good answers to my last question about this in bash
(if it might help you, here are complete solutions in awk or jq)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68153214/json-get-fitting-the-numbers-in-a-row-and-add-a-0-in-front-of-every-1-9-number)
but, now i have to move to python3..

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit3:**

I finally succeeded in extracting the values.
how can this be further filtering?
to get it as shown in the example below?

```
>>> import json
>>> import base64
>>> from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
>>>
>>> credentials = b'kodi:kodi'
>>> encoded_credentials = base64.b64encode(credentials)
>>> authorization = b'Basic ' + encoded_credentials
>>>
>>> headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': authorization }
>>> url = 'http://192.168.1.10:8080/jsonrpc'
>>> data = [{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Player.GetProperties","params":[1,["time"]],"id":17},{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Player.GetItem","params":[1,["file"]],"id":18}]
>>>
>>> json_data = json.dumps(data)
>>> post_data = json_data.encode('utf-8')
>>> request = Request(url, post_data, headers)
>>> result = urlopen(request)
>>> print(result.read())
b'[{"id":17,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"time":{"hours":0,"milliseconds":914,"minutes":52,"seconds":59}}},{"id":18,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"item":{"file":"smb://192.168.1.10/n filmek 720p/The.Expendables.3.2014.Hybrid.READ.NFO.Extended.720p.BluRay.DTS.x264.HuN-TRiNiTY/theexpendables3.720p.hybrid.ex-trinity.mkv","id":340,"label":"The Expendables 3","type":"movie"}}}]'
```

which I would like to filter further for this:

```
smb://192.168.1.10/@.mkv
0
52
59
```

and I would like to "convert" it to this

```
smb://192.168.1.10/@.mkv
005259
```

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 thanks, I've written down what I've got so far but I don't know who's helped by a total beginner describing what he's messing up

Comment: What is it you want?  Please be specific.  Also show an example of what you are getting as well as an example of what you want.

Comment: What is the input and what is the desired output?  If you can't explain what you want as a result, you can't expect any help

Comment: @itprorh66 I edited it so it makes more sense now?

Comment: I would begin by reviewing [Working With JSON Data in Python](https://realpython.com/python-json/) for a basic understanding of how to filter json.  Once you have reviewed, and have some code to work with, we can help.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import base64
import requests

credentials = b'kodi:kodi'
encoded_credentials = base64.b64encode(credentials)
authorization = b'Basic ' + encoded_credentials
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': authorization }
url = 'http://192.168.1.10:8080/jsonrpc?Base'
data = [
    {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Player.GetProperties","params":[1,["time"]],"id":17},
    {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Player.GetItem","params":[1,["file"]],"id":18}]
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
result = response.json()
h,m,s = map(int, [result[0]['result']['time'][val] for val in ['hours','minutes','seconds']])
time = f'{h:02}{m:02}{s:02}'
print(result[1]['result']['item']['file'],time, sep='\n', file=open("c:\\kodi\\save.txt", "w"))
```

save.txt

```
smb://192.168.1.10/@.mkv
005259
```